# Problem with Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I attempt to create a Android Project for the first time, I get an error saying "an SDK Target must be specified. I looked on the internet, and I couldn't find a fix to my problem. In the Android SDK manager, I have downloaded almost every available package, and none of htem fixed my problem.

At the console window at the bottom of eclipse, I get these errors:

[2011-04-11 20:09:57 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring platform 'android-11': android.jar is missing.

[2011-04-11 20:22:22 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Did something not install correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Preferences window, select Android in the menu on the left. On the
right side of the window, click Browse, find the location of the Android SDK on your
hard drive, and enter it in the SDK Location field. Eclipse needs this information to be
able to access all the tools that are supplied with Android, such as the emulator.

while starting a new project, dont forget to select the build of the android OS you will be using.
Best luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the preferences in Eclipse and select "Android" from the left-side menu, do you see an "SDK location" listed? You'll want to make sure that that points to the folder where you downloaded the various SDK packages.